# how to map Android Studio device name to ADB device name?

Tags: android-studio, adb

In Android Studio's Device Manager, the virtual device name is

```
New Device API 30 1
```

After I launched it from Android Studio, I can see it in 'adb devices' output as

```
C:\>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

If I only have one device running, there is no confusion.

If I have multiple, is there a way to tell which is which?

**Background**

when I start emulator in a script, I need to use the Android Studio device name.

```
emulator -avd New_Device_API_30_1
```

but when I connect my Appium Python client to Appium server, I need to use the ADB device name
in desired_cap

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(f"http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", {"appium:deviceName":"emulator-5554", ...})
```

I need to automate these two steps.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the port when you start the emulator then you will know the device name

```
emulator -avd New_Device_API_30_1 -port 5558
```

then you will see

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5558   device
```

otherwise they will be selected in the order they are started.